# What is the appropriate title for neutral name?

Tags: word-usage, forms-of-address

I want to send an email to someone that I only know the name of them, and their name is a neutral one. So I'm unsure to use Ms. or Mr.??

In this situation, what should I do? Is there any title for this kind of occasions?

Comment: You might say "Dear *Fname Lname*", or just do some research to find the right title.

Comment: More specifically, if you Google the name in quotes and add a word indicating some sort of affiliation, an image search will usually reveal the sex. E.g.: **"Drew Faust" Harvard**